# wpf mvvm change binded list of datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

i want to switch datagrid binded list by another list

```
    class A
    {
       propx, 
       propy, 
       propz
    } 
    class B
    {
       propw, 
       prope
    } 
    List<A> listA
    List<B> listB
    List<??> Anylist

    wpf <Datagrid ItemSource={Binding  AnyList} >
 
    if(condition1)
       Anylist=listA
    if(condition2)
       Anylist=listB
```

tried casting list, i failed.
if this can done, what is easy way, use `datatemplate` on xaml or use generic `list<T>` conversion on `viewmodel` or any other method, in any way how it is done

Comment: Declare AnyList as non-generic IList or IEnumerable.

Comment: This isn't C# dude.

Comment: You can use object as type or create an Interface and implement the interface in A and B